# Error message about unused parameter in apriori R function

Tags: r, apriori, market-basket-analysis

I am new to R and trying to create a function that will dynamically perform the apriori function depending on the parameters. I am stuck when trying to define my rules. Any assistance on the below error would be much appreciated!

I have thoroughly tried to google my error and looked at similar questions on stackoverflow but have not found a solution that works for me.

```
library(arules)
library(arulesViz)
library(RColorBrewer)

## Define function
apriori <- function (file_name, minsup, minconf, unique_id_first_column) {

 data <- read.csv(file_name)

if (unique_id_first_column == 1)
{
## remove first column
data <- data[ -1]
}

 ## Replace any missing values with 0
  data[is.na(data)] <- 0

 ## Turns into T/F Values
 data <- apply(data,2,as.logical)


#Create Frequent Itemsets

rules <- apriori(data, parameter=list(support=.6,target="frequent 
itemsets"))

## AFTER THIS LINE THE FOLLOWING ERROR IS PRODUCED
## Error in apriori(data, parameter = list(support = 0.6, target = 
## "frequent itemsets")) : 
## unused argument (parameter = list(support = 0.6, target = "frequent 
## itemsets"))


return (data)
}

#get user inputs

file_name <- readline(prompt="Enter File Name & Extension:")
min_sup <- as.numeric(readline(prompt="Enter Minimum Support:"))
min_conf <- as.numeric(readline(prompt="Enter Minimum Confidence:"))
unique_id_first_column <- as.numeric(readline(prompt="Enter a 1 if first 
column is the unique key:"))



apriori(file_name, min_sup, min_conf, unique_id_first_column)


##rm(list=ls())
```

Comment: You seem to be calling the `apriori` function within its own function definition?

Comment: You are not calling `apriori` properly within itself. Maybe try to explain what you are trying to do there?

Comment: I see!! Didn’t think about that. Thank you!!